# Value of a user defined function

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have an User Defined Function in Excel 2010 VBA.

In a cell `A1`, I call that function: `=myfunction()` and the returned value (as Integer) is showed correctly in the `A1` cell.

My concern is how can I obtain the value of A1 cell from other function in VBA. I want that `MyOtherFunction()` obtain the number of `A1`.

The cell `A1` has `=MyFunction()`

```
function MyFunction() as integer
   ......
   MyFunction = 99
End function
```

I see correctly the value `99` in `A1`.

```
function MyOtherFunction()
   dim valor as integer
   valor =  Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("yyy").Range("A1").Value
End function
```

In that function the variable `valor` return `0` instead `99`.

Comment: Is my answer difficult to understand?

Comment: No Siddharth, thanks but the returned value allways is zero.
I have this: Workbooks("xxx.xlsm").Sheets("yyy").Range("A1").Value
The value I get is 0 but the A1 cell has the result of =myfunction()

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the right sheet in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`?

Comment: I see you edited your comment. Can you update your question with the exact code that you are using? I posted the code after testing it.

Comment: I wrote the code, but I dont know how to align to show it correctly!

Comment: Where is `MyOtherFunction`? in `Workbooks("xxx.xlsm")` or some other workbook?

Comment: Also shouldn't `valor` be `MyOtherFunction` or you meant it to be `Sub MyOtherFunction()`

Comment: I tried something. I wrote directly the number 456 in A1 cell (deleting the call to =MyFunction() and the variable "valor" obtain the value correctly.
I don't know what's the reason.

Comment: Siddharth, all functions are in the same Workbooks("xxx.xlsm"). Perhaps my comment about wrote directly a number can clear the issue?

Comment: May I see the workbook. If yes then you can upload it in a file sharing site and  share the link here?

Comment: I have no problem to share it, but the woorkbook is part of an Excel application linked with other books and has a lot of functions.
I think if has any restriction in Excel to UDF.

Comment: You can create a sample just with the relevant functions?

Comment: Yes, I'll do it soon. Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: I just solved the issue. I started with a new workbook to make a sample and it's worked. I copied all the functions and still works.
I think it was a code or format that disturbed the proccess.
Thank you again for your kindly assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function MyOtherFunction(Rng As Range) As Whatever
    '~~> Rest of the code
End Function
```

**In a worksheet as a UDF**

```
=MyOtherFunction(A1)
```

**In VBA**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret
    Ret = MyOtherFunction(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just write:

```
Function MyOtherFunction()
    MyOtherFunction = Range("A1").Value
End Function
```

Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Thanks, but the returned value is allways zero

Comment: Maybe you're not referring to the correct workbook or worksheet?